# Trying to find the smallest value of a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the smallest value of the vectors with a function and when I try and run it, the first vector works out ok while the second gives -5 instead of -7.

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but you should add spaces around `<-`.

Comment: Not sure why you need a function with a loop. `min(-c(5,4,7,5,3,2))` works fine.

Comment: On your third line, you have `{}` closing off the evaluation of the loop before it does anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `min`, but you've just got a problem with the braces `{}` on your `for` loop:

```
my_min <- function(x){
  x.min <- x[1]
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i] < x.min)
    {
      x.min <- x[i]
    }
  }
  return(x.min)
}


my_min(c(5,4,7,5,3,2))
my_min(-c(5,4,7,5,3,2))
```

You weren't actually looping over anything. Also, R starts its indexing at 1.

Comment: Also a veryyyy small improvement could be start the loop at `2:length(x)`

Comment: but also the takeaway here should be 'dont use a for loop for something that is vectorized'

Answer (score 3):

Looks like @mickey answered your immediate question, but this is a good time to reiterate the importance of leveraging the strengths of the programming language. In this case, R has the built in `min()` function which operates on the entire vector at once. As the example below shows, it is nearly 30x faster than the for loop for a vector of length `1e8`, which really isn't that big:

```r
my_min <- function(x){
  x.min <- x[1]
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i] < x.min)
    {
      x.min <- x[i]
    }
  }
  return(x.min)
}

set.seed(42)
vec <- rnorm(1e8)
system.time(my_min(vec))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.81    0.00    5.94
system.time(min(vec))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>     0.2     0.0     0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>